# How to set on touch event for child expandablelistview

Tags: java, android, mobile

Have to ask for help. I'm new to developing for Android, and I have got a question on how to assign the onTouch event to child element ExpandableListView. I added elements dynamically (parent and child) [made like this](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/10/android-expandablelistview-example.html), is there some way to that onChildClick could continue to assign event onTouch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try returning false in the onChildClick method. Normally this means that the event has not been processed. If you return false, the event should be passed down.

```
elv.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v){
                    return false; 
                }
            });
```